# Decrypt CRC32 using static key in php (used C# class to generate CRC added)

Tags: c#, php, encryption, decode, crc32

This is my class to create a CRC32 hash. Its not my class I found it on internet ofc.. But to the point I can't manage to get SSL working or AES because I have really only basic coding knowledge. 
I am making launcher for my little game nothing big I dont need super strong encryption I only need to hide client queries from casuals.

Somewhere on the internet people said CRC32 is one way hash but it obviously is not. 
Within the class is function for encrypt and decrypt both work very well.

I have tested sending hashed and unhashed
In future I plan to create a hidden file on users harddrive with random text and take its checksum and use it as the key for CRC generation and also as identifier for player machine. The key will be send only at first launch of application. I know its not secure but its enough for me.

```
// Copyright (c) Damien Guard.  All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
// You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
// Originally published at http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Namechanger
{
/// <summary>
/// Implements a 32-bit CRC hash algorithm compatible with Zip etc.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Crc32 should only be used for backward compatibility with older file formats
/// and algorithms. It is not secure enough for new applications.
/// If you need to call multiple times for the same data either use the HashAlgorithm
/// interface or remember that the result of one Compute call needs to be ~ (XOR) before
/// being passed in as the seed for the next Compute call.
/// </remarks>
public class StringEncryption
{
    private readonly Random random;
    private readonly byte[] key;
    private readonly RijndaelManaged rm;
    private readonly UTF8Encoding encoder;

    public object Assert { get; private set; }





    public StringEncryption()
    {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        this.encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        this.key = Convert.FromBase64String("cGFzc3dvcmRz");
    }

    public string Encrypt(string unencrypted)
    {
        var vector = new byte[16];
        this.random.NextBytes(vector);
        var cryptogram = vector.Concat(this.Encrypt(this.encoder.GetBytes(unencrypted), vector));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cryptogram.ToArray());
    }

    public string Decrypt(string encrypted)
    {
        var cryptogram = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        if (cryptogram.Length < 17)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid encrypted string", "encrypted");
        }

        var vector = cryptogram.Take(16).ToArray();
        var buffer = cryptogram.Skip(16).ToArray();
        return this.encoder.GetString(this.Decrypt(buffer, vector));
    }

    private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer, byte[] vector)
    {
        var encryptor = this.rm.CreateEncryptor(this.key, vector);
        return this.Transform(buffer, encryptor);
    }

    private byte[] Decrypt(byte[] buffer, byte[] vector)
    {
        var decryptor = this.rm.CreateDecryptor(this.key, vector);
        return this.Transform(buffer, decryptor);
    }

    private byte[] Transform(byte[] buffer, ICryptoTransform transform)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    public void EncryptDecrypt()
    {
        // Arrange
        var subject = new StringEncryption();
        var originalString = "Testing123!£$";

        // Act
        var encryptedString1 = subject.Encrypt(originalString);
        var encryptedString2 = subject.Encrypt(originalString);
        var decryptedString1 = subject.Decrypt(encryptedString1);
        var decryptedString2 = subject.Decrypt(encryptedString2);
    }
}
```

Mycode what I am sending to php

```
var subject = new StringEncryption();
var originalString = "" + getCheckSumFile(assemblypath) + " " + unixTimestamp + "";
var hashed = subject.Encrypt(originalString);
var unhashed = subject.Decrypt(hashed);

string str = string.Concat("http://127.0.0.1/here/?nick=", nick, "&server=", server, "&data=", hashed);
Network.getData(str);
```

So far everyting works for me only I dont know how to decrypt the CRC32 with a key using php? I havent find any info on this at all most php guides uses only crc hash with no intention to decrypt it with key.

Comment: Yes it is one way, that's what a hash is..... what your'e asking is if you can recreate the cow from hamburger

Comment: But I can decrypt it like this ? It wont work if I have the key also on server side?       var hashed = subject.Encrypt(originalString);
                                var unhashed = subject.Decrypt(hashed);

Comment: If you can decrypt it, it isn't a hash; and CRC32 is a hash.... you cannot "decrypt" a crc32; all you can do is check if a string generates the same crc32 value

Comment: For encryption is used the same key for each client everytime and the key will be paired with username..        public StringEncryption()
    {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        this.encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        this.key = Convert.FromBase64String("cGFzc3dvcmRz");
    }

Comment: Or what is best option to just hide what client send to me?

Comment: Basically this site doest what I need https://md5hashing.net/hash/crc32

Comment: Have you read what it says on that site? `we offer reverse decryption via our database (~800M records, and counting).` They don't decrypt anything, they simply do a lookup in a giant database of strings and hashes looking for a value that they already know, it's a simple database lookup of known hashes

Comment: Ok thank you for your patience. I have found my solution I will only only do string hashed = Base64Encode(hash); and encode the assembly hash + timestamp + some salt this way the hash will be different everytime and the client files are obstructed so nobody who will se the code will know its not encrypted. And the base64 can be easily decoded with php. Just posting here my final solution for anybody who is not up to the task to set proper encryption as me. As I said I only need it to be unreadable by sniffing packets.